# setInterval cannot be stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have an element move on the left when the mouse if on the left side of the screen, right when on the other side. I want to activate a function that makes the element move when the mouse enter a zone, and stop that function when it exits.

I've been trying to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` but impossible to make it work. The `setInterval` works, and the function starts, but I can't make it stop.

Here is the code, declared in an init function:

```
var intervalLeft;
    var intervalRight;

    var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        if (currentMousePos.x < 200) {
            console.log('LEFT');
            intervalLeft = setInterval(goleft, 500);
        } else if (currentMousePos.x > $width-200) {
            console.log('RIGHT');
            intervalRight = setInterval(goright, 500);
        } else {
            console.log('STOP');
            clearInterval(intervalRight);
            clearInterval(intervalLeft);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a new `interval` on every `mousemove` event so you clear only the last started one. You should check if you've already started an `interval` and only start a new one if you haven't/it's cleared

Comment: Oh I thought that the `interval` objects were only updating themselves, they were in fact multiplying. It works fine now, thank you so much!